# Liquibase for opensearch/ elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, liquibase, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, liquibase-maven-plugin

I have been using Liquibase for maintaining postgreSQL changes.Is there a way I can use it in the same manner with Opensearch/ Elasticsearch?
Is there any existing plugin, or any future plan to support another noSQL database such as opensearch? I couldn't find any references related to this. How to check the changelogs?